# Components update in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

So in plain react, setState triggers the render method. Now, about Redux, let's say I fire an action, the state returned from the reducer(s) is totally new, so it sounds like every component should get updated, though I know it's not true because when I debug my app I can see it, plus it sounds like awful performance. So my question is, does redux look in each component what state slice it needs? in mapStateToProps? and generally how does Redux decide when to call the render method?

I know Redux has optimizations in it... thanks...

Comment: `totally new` doesn't mean a complete deep copy.  Unless you are changing every node of the state tree.

Answer (score 1):

A Redux store offers a `subscribe()` method.  When you use `connect()`, it generates wrapper components that automatically subscribe to the store when they are created.  Each individual connected component is a separate subscriber.

When an action is dispatched, the store runs all the subscription callbacks.  The wrapper components then call `store.getState()`.  As a first check, if the root state object is `===` identical to the previous one, the component will stop there.  (This is one reason why direct mutation of state in a reducer is bad.)

The next step is to call the provided `mapState` function and pass in the current state object.  The wrapper component then compares the contents of the object returned from `mapState` against the contents of the object returned *last* time, using a shallow equality comparison check.  If any of the contents have changed *based on that shallow check*, then the component knows it needs to re-render the "real" component with the new data.  (Again, the "shallow" check is another reason why mutation is bad.)

Comment: good answer, you might want to point out that `redux` and `react-redux` are 2 separate modules. :)